# Calculate the week ending date in oracle using Saturday as the week end date

Tags: oracle, datetime, time-series

Given a field in Oracle that contains dates, how would you calculate what the week ending date is using Sun thru Sat as your week.  For example, if the date is 1/26/2015 (which is a Monday), the query should return 1/31/2015 (which is a Saturday.  If the date is 1/31/2015, then the query should return 1/31/2015.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given any particular date / time value, this expression will return midnight of the preceding Sunday.

```
 TRUNC(whatever_time,'DAY')
```

So, you can do stuff like this:

```
 SELECT TRUNC(whatever_time,'DAY') week_starting,
        TRUNC(whatever_time,'DAY')  + 6 week_ending,
        SUM(sales)
   FROM table
  GROUP BY TRUNC(whatever_time,'DAY')
```

and you'll get what you need.

Notice that `TRUNC(whatever_time,'DAY')` honors the Oracle session initialization parameter called “NLS_TERRITORY”. For example, in Europe Monday is considered the first business day of the week. Try this.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=GERMANY;
SELECT TRUNC( DATE '2013-12-31', 'DAY'),
       TRUNC( DATE '2014-01-03', 'DAY')
  FROM DUAL;
```

A complete writeup of this is here: http://www.plumislandmedia.net/sql-time-processing/using-sql-report-time-intervals-oracle/